# OpenPopup Marker Bug?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

Hi when I try to open the popup of an marker right after creating it, it won't work.

```
var marker = L.marker([x, y],{icon:greenIcon}).bindPopup(markerString);
marker.openPopup();
console.log(marker.getPopup().isOpen());
```

log -> false
Do I have to add my marker to the map first ?

As I have an huge Array of markers, I create a featureGroup first, add my markers to it and add my featureGroup to my Map. How can I Access my marker in my featureGroup to open the Popup afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to add my marker to the map first ?

Yes, yes, yes. Otherwise, how does the marker know to which map it is related to?

> How can I Access my marker in my featureGroup to open the Popup afterwards?

Simply keep a variable for each of your markers (could be in an array), or iterate the markers in your Feature Group to determine the appropriate marker based on some criteria (if you have some). It is totally up to the application developer.